# simmechanics_to_urdf problem

Tags: urdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi Dear ROS Community,
i want to import a CAD model from solid-work to gazebo. i use this command
**rosrun simmechanics_to_urdf convert.py Desktop/pan.xml xml > Desktop/panto.xml**
but this isn't work:(
i search in net and i think, i must define "Paramater Yaml File". but there is not any help for this part.
so can anyone help me *very simply* (because it my first project with ros:D ) how i can correct my command?
If anyone can help I will be very thankful

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10098/simmechanics_to_urdf-problem/) by [sina](https://answers.ros.org/users/616/sina/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2011-05-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I finally got around to writing a tutorial! Sorry about the delay.

[Converting SimMechanics to URDF](http://www.ros.org/wiki/simmechanics_to_urdf/Tutorials/Converting%20SimMechanics%20To%20URDF)

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2011-07-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If someone construct/post examples with simple simmechanic models that translate to misbehaving urdf's, it can definitely help us with further debugging.  Thanks.

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2011-07-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1